# JSF2.2 getter and setter in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm a beginner with JSF and I'm trying to do a login page but I have a problem with getting data from facelet.
The bean is managed in faces-config.xml as SessionScope.

```
public class LoginBean
{

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;

    private String sqlName;
    private String sqlEmail;
    private String sqlPassword;

    public LoginBean() {
        initDB();
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public void initDB() {
        try{
            //load driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");

            //get connection
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/userdb", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("Connection estabilshed");

            String sqlQuery = "select name, email, password from users "+
                            "where email=? and password=?";

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);


            ps.setString(1, getEmail());
            ps.setString(2, getPassword());


            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                sqlName = rs.getString(1);
                sqlEmail = rs.getString(2).toString();
                sqlPassword = rs.getString(3).toString();

            }
            else {
                rs.close();

            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String checkLogin() throws SQLException {

        if(email.equalsIgnoreCase(sqlEmail)) {
            if(password.equals(sqlPassword)) {

                return "valid";
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Password Invalid");
                return "invalid";
            }
        }
        else {

            System.err.println("Email Invalid");
            return "invalid";       
        }
    }
}
```

*login.xhtml*

```
            <h:inputText id="emailInputText" styleClass="inputText" required="true" 
                    value="#{loginBean.email}"/>
            <h:inputSecret id="passwordInputText" styleClass="inputSecret" required="true" 
                    value="#{loginBean.password}"/>


        <h:commandButton styleClass="commandButton" id="loginButton" value="Login" type="submit"
                    action="#{loginBean.checkLogin}"/>

        <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
            <p><span class="info">?</span><a href="#">Forgot Password</a> • <a href="#" >Register</a></p>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

The problem is that

```
ps.setString(1, getEmail());
ps.setString(2, getPassword());
```

are both null and `checkLogin()` will allways return "invalid".
I don't know why this happens and how to fix it.

P.S. Sorry for my lousy English. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *applyValues* stage is responsible for setting the values received in the request.

Since you are trying to use `email` and `password` in the constructor, those values will be null because the container did not have time to apply those values. This is done *after* the object is created.

Some options are:

- Use `@PostConstruct` in order to fire an event after *applyValues* is done (dont do it!)
- Get values from the database in your `checkLogin()` event (which I recommend).

Another problem is that a session managed bean will only be created once, so you would have trouble.

I would suggest you to do all your login logic inside your `checkLogin()`.

Also, do not use `@SessionScoped` if you do not need it. Keep it simple with `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please give me some references books or links where can I understand better jsf ?

Comment: @DanielDeliu I think the best place to start is in the Java EE  Tutorials in [The Web Tier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partwebtier.htm#BNADP). I would suggest you reading the entire Part III, not only about Faces. It will give you a nice understanding about the JavaServer Faces concepts, and also let you practice while doing it.